# Using angular-local-storage Inside a Service?

Tags: angularjs, angular-local-storage

I am trying to use the angular-local-storage module (https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage), version 0.2.2 (according to bower) in a service within my application. I seem to be having issues with it when I call it within a service, but it works fine when I put it inside a controller.

I have it configured like this:

```
angular.module('myApp', [ 'LocalStorageModule' ])
    .config(function (localStorageServiceProvider) {
        localStorageServiceProvider
          .setPrefix('test')
          .setStorageType('localStorage');
     })...
```

And then in my service, I have it like this (simplified, for testing purposes):

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .service('UserService', [ 'localStorageService',
        function(localStorageService) {
            return {
                save: function() {
                    localStorageService.set('user', 'me');
                }
            };
    }]);
```

This code yields an error of:

> TypeError: localStorageService.set is not a function

On the other hand, if I place the exact same code into a controller (indeed, the controller who calls this service), everything works as expected. Does angular-local-storage not work within services?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are missing return statement:  return {
                save: function() {
                   return localStorageService.set('user', 'me');
                }
            };

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does work for me with minor tweaks. See below code snippet.

```js
angular.module('myApp', [ 'LocalStorageModule' ])
  .config(function (localStorageServiceProvider) {
    localStorageServiceProvider
      .setPrefix('test')
      .setStorageType('localStorage');
  })
  .service('UserService', [ 'localStorageService',
    function(localStorageService) {
      return {
        save: function() {
          localStorageService.set('user', 'me');
        }
      };
    }])
  .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, UserService){
    $scope.test = function(){
      console.debug('save called');
      UserService.save();
    };
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <button ng-click="test()">Test</button>
    </div>

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="home.html">
    Lorem ipsum
  </script>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-local-storage/dist/angular-local-storage.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Weird! Maybe I should look at why my configuration, where the services and controllers are not all chained together, doesn't seem to work, while it works in your example when things are all in one place. Thanks for the hint!